# How to properly index

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a table on a database that has different poll options. There is another table with polls.

The idea is that given a poll_id I want to get as fast as possible all its options.

This are the table columns: `opt_id, poll_id, opt_text, opt_votes`.

I would like the opt_id not to be an auto_increment but just the id (1 to N options) within the poll, so to me the primary key is given by both the poll_id and the option_id, right?

What I want is to have a proper index so that a query such `SELECT * FROM options WHERE poll_id=X` takes as less as possible, but I don't know if just by setting the primary key to these two fields is enough or I have to set an index somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For `SELECT * FROM options WHERE poll_id=X`, `INDEX(poll_id)` is optimal.  If you already have `PRIMARY KEY(poll_id)`, then that is sufficient.  (A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE KEY` which is an `INDEX`.)

[*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

*Please* provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there is too much hand-waving in your description of the tables.

And show us any other `SELECTs`; they may need other indexes.